# Optimize React Multiple Theme With Ant Design

Tags: reactjs, antd

i have a webapp using Ant Design with two (can be more) themes.
I follow this solution to defined each themes by override Ant less variable, but it now include all of compile style into head, i want to find some option to optimize it (something like lazy load file, . . ) or some better way to multiple theme with Ant

Light Theme:

```
[theme='light'] { @import '~antd/dist/antd.less'; @body-background: red }
```

Dark Themme:

```
[theme='dark'] { @import '~antd/dist/antd.less'; @body-background: gold}
```

then import all it into app.tsx;

Tks a lot.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2laF.png)

Comment: what is your exact question?

Comment: i found this above way to multiple themes with Ant Design, but is all load the css into my page. I hope to find someway like lazy loading/dynamic load in runtime.